# Bazel - What is the equivalent of CMake find_package but in Bazel?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, bazel, bazel-rules

My `Bazel` project contains a `cc_binary` with a `main.cpp` file, which includes some header file: `foo.h`

On my `main.cpp`, I am invoking a function `myFunc()` that is defined in `foo.h`, but the implementation of it is somewhere inside some library installed on my system, which I don't know which one but know the location.

Let's say it's here: `/usr/local/bar/...` (inside this folder I have a bunch of `libxxx.so` files)

If I compile I get an undefined reference to `myFunc(..)`.

Using `CMake` I can compile just by adding the following line on my `CMakeLists.txt` file: `find_package(BAR)` and get the necessary libraries.

What is the equivalent procedure in `Bazel`?

Something like creating a `cc_library` that contains a glob of all `*.so` files?
What is a good practice here?